# Regex Notepad ++: Extract middle part URL

Tags: regex, url, notepad++

I have these URL:

```
http://web.com/George-Eliot/5234-20412_4-54534.html
http://web.com/Reading-HD/3434-20412_4-43454.html
```

How to extract middle part: **George-Eliot** and **Reading-HD** ? I mean removing all except middle part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Use this regex `^http:\/\/[^\/]*\/([^\/]*).*` and then replace the matched characters by `\1`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dL7oF8/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*\/(?=[^\/]*\/[^\/]*$)|\/[^\/]*$
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dL7oF8/4

Comment: @user3373322 you can try this as well.It will not need any replacement